# Linux RPM-spec does not copy packages to destination folder

Tags: linux, package, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have a package, with the directories named *lib*, *sample*, *api*, *doc* under a parent directory *`%{name}-%{version}`*.  I want to generate an **RPM** package out of these folders. This **rpm** package should unfold these directories under a client specified relocated destination folder. A `%{name}-%{version}` folder, that has all package directories, is compressed in a *tar.gz* and kept under a **SOURCE** folder. After reading spec documentation and web resources, I made the following spec file.

```
Name: BATMAN
Version: 1.0.0
Release:    1%{?dist}
Summary: A cricket match program
Group: System Environment/Base
License: MEMEME
Source0: BATMAN-1.0.0.tar.gz
Prefix: /tmp
%define reloc_dir /tmp
%define target_dir %{reloc_dir}/manish
%define installdir PingPong-v%{version}

%description
Here comes the description

%prep
rm -rf %{_topdir}/BUILD/*
rm -rf %{target_dir}

%setup

%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}
cp -R %{_topdir}/BUILD/%{name}-%{version}/* %{buildroot}

###What should come down here##############
mkdir -p %{target_dir}
install -dD %{buildroot}/* %{target_dir}
###########################################

#find %{target_dir} -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
#find %{target_dir} -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
#chmod -R 755 %{target_dir}

%files
/sample/sample.cpp
/header/BATMAN.hpp
/header/BALLMAN.hpp
/header/BUSYMAN.hpp
/header/BUSHYMAN.hpp
/doc/BATMAN.docx
/lib/BATMAN.so
/lib/BALLMAN.so
/lib/BUSYMAN.so
/lib/BUSHYMAN.so

%defattr(-,root,root,0755)

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%changelog
```

The `%setup` command successfully unfolds compressed folder under `%{_topdir}/BUILD/`. Then I copied these files to `%{buildroot}` (because `%files` tag was expecting files to be present under **BUILDROOT** to package). Packaging of all these files is also done successfully but when I run `sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps <Package-Vesrion-Arch>.rpm` command on resulting rpm then I donlt see any folder getting created under destination side or any copying happening. Although it shows that package is being installed successfully; `rpm -qa` has an entry for my package.

Comment: Please add the output of `rpm -ql -p package.rpm`.  Your `%files` section should add a `%{reloc}` to all entries (or something like this).  Ie, `%{reloc}/samples/sample.cpp`, etc.  I think you have placed them in the **root** directory.  You might like to use `chroot` when you test installs.

Comment: Can you clarify this: 'client specified relocated destination folder'? Why are the users installing this not using --root if they're going to be using the rpm into a different directory?